# How to find Chrome warning message box using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, chromium, dom

I'm designing a site which uses client side Java as a loader. In chrome to load my page it asks users permission. At that time I want show a custom error message on my page. So My question is "Is it possible to find those type warning using JavaScript / jQuery / Any other mechanism ??"

[image: warning message in chrome]

Comment: `short answer:` No. `long answer:` This would be part of the Chromium Kit. You would need to develop an Add-On to be able to manage and modify Global Warnings in Chrome. This would mean they would need to install an Add-On just for your site before they're able to interact with it the way you intend. So..`Long story short` No.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this by typing `navigator.javaEnabled()`. For more info read [this link](http://javatester.org/enabled.html)